# Volume form for $SE(n)$ and/or $E(n)$.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I wonder what happens when you construct the Tiling spaces considering the natural action of $SE(n)$ or $E(n)$ rather than $\mathbb R^n$. In order to do that, I need to understand both the riemannian metric, and the volume form of the considered group. Are they unique?

Could you suggest an example based reference on Lie groups?